# Not able to display text Total in CSV for custom grid

Tags: admin, grid, csv, totals

I have created a custom grid in Magento admin and have also added the total at below the grid .However I am not able to get the text "Total" when the grid is exported to CSV or XML.

```
 $this->addColumn('created', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('extension')->__('Date'),
        'index' => 'center',
        'index'     => 'created_at',
        'type' => 'date',
        'align' => 'left',            
        'width' => '90px',
        'format'    => 'MM-dd-Y',  
        'totals_label'  => Mage::helper('extension')->__('Total'),
    ));
```

Comment: What does the rest of the grid class lookl like? Did you use `$this->setCountTotals(true)`?

Comment: Yes I have used protected $_countTotals = true;